# how to show a new window on the second or third monitor of uwp win 10

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp

I want my program to be able to select the monitor on which a new window will be opened

now my code looks like this:

```
AppWindow appWindow = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
Frame OpenPage1 = new Frame();
OpenPage1.Navigate(typeof(Projector));
ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(appWindow, OpenPage1);
appWindow.Presenter.RequestPresentation(AppWindowPresentationKind.FullScreen);

await appWindow.TryShowAsync();
```

It opens a window on the current monitor. I want the window to open on the selected monitor

Additional question: How can I prevent this window from collapsing?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but there's [AppWindow.RequestMoveToDisplayRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.WindowManagement.AppWindow.RequestMoveToDisplayRegion?view=winrt-22000) that lets you pick the monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to show a new window on the second or third monitor of uwp win 10

As Raymond Chen said you could use `RequestMoveToDisplayRegion` method to display AppWindow in secondary `DisplayRegion`.

For code sample you could refer to AppWindow  official code sample [Scenario2_DisplayRegion](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/AppWindow/cs/Scenario2_DisplayRegion.xaml.cs).

```
 DisplayRegion secondaryDisplayRegion = GetOtherDisplayRegion(ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().GetDisplayRegions()[0]); 
 if (secondaryDisplayRegion != null)
  {
     appWindow.RequestMoveToDisplayRegion(secondaryDisplayRegion);
  }
```